# Docker - Multipe NodeJS commands

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I want to run app.js multiple times inside a docker container. How should the CMD looks like in docker file for running it multiple times?

CMD ["node", "app.js"]

Comment: At what interval? How many times?

Comment: Parallel.. around 20 times. I need concurrent nodejs programs running in the same container.

Comment: Docker RUN and CMD don’t take & to start a process in the background. You can write a shell script which does so, then call that from your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop:

```
CMD for i in `seq 10`; do node app.js; done
```